# How to click <a>class in table, Selenium (Calendar)

Tags: java, html, selenium

I'm using 'Selenium2(WebDriver)' in Eclipse (Java)

How can I click  class in table (Calendar)?

I'm testing Calendar. Everytime I change the month, (ex)March-> July
the table and  is changed. because All of month's table structure(class,.. id..) are same.

Originally,

`**//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]/a**`

is click code.
But, this code clicks same location. whatever the date is.

I can explain more. 
ex) `//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[5]/a`
is click code. 
fiducially 2014.08 calendar, 2014,8,29 is clicked. 
               and,fiducially 2014.10 calendar, 2014.10.31 is clicked

Well, I just want click date ! 1st, 2nd, 3rd... not tr[] td[]. I mean, 2014.08.25 
2014.10.25 .... I just want click 25 ! 
How can I click that Element ?

Comment: Would be very useful to see the actual html you are testing against. At least provide the relevant part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would help you exactly for your page, but i would have to see all your html. You have to create xpath with variable as a date to pass a parameter in method. It would look something like this.

public void chooseDate(String **date**) {

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]/table/tbody//td[.='" **+ date +** "']")).click();

}

This way it would click any date you want.

Comment: I am glad it worked! Please close this question, by clicking "V" sign on the left side of my answer.